# How to count value from string in for loop in vb?

Tags: vb.net, string

i have a string containing value like this

```
  i ={11212}
     {22121}
     {3113}
     {4122}
     {5121}  
     ......
     ......
```

How can i count the total no of value  ?

Comment: Do you mean the number of values or the sum of the values?

Comment: Is that a string or an array of integers?

Comment: the no of value of value present in the string

Comment: i read the value from listbox and put it here and i decrare it as string

Comment: `listBox.Items.Count`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LinQ to count the number of brackets:

```
Dim Count = (From s In i Select s Where s = "{").Count
```

And you should rename `i` to something sensible in my opinion.

For when you have just any delimiter in your text and want to count single numbers you can as well use a regular expression and count the matches:

```
Dim InputString = "{11212}{22121}{4122}12312"
Dim rx As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[0-9]+")
Dim NumberCount = rx.Matches(InputString).Count 'Outputs 4
```

This searches for occurences of numbers of any length in your input.

Comment: is there any process ...in for each loop

Comment: if it contains only value not the " {"

Comment: instead of "{" you may put the separator that separates each value from another, whether it was a space or \n ... and add one to the count at the end.

Comment: Why? The solution is adaptable and works. This is not a "Do-my-homework" service.